# assign a memory address given by argv to a pointer in c

Tags: c, pointers, memory, argv

I have a function in C which gets a pointer and prints its disassembly code.

```
void print_dis(void *addr) {
    print_dis(addr);
}
```

everything is working just fine but now I would like to pass this memory address from the command line as argv.

How can I pass a memory address and assign it to a pointer so it will run like:

my_prog 0x1234567890abcd

and that print_dis will get this address as addr

Comment: Are you looking for a function like `strtoull()`? Perhaps something like `void *addr = (void*) strtoull(argv[1]+2, 0, 16);`?

Comment: strtoull will return to me a new long long value that has the same value as the string, right? how can I use that as an address?

Comment: Are you okay with just redirecting/piping the stdout of "program1" to  the stdin of your second program??

Comment: not really, I would like to use the same method with a kernel module as well

Comment: You can redirect the output of a kernel module, no? `>`

Comment: Look [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast)?

Comment: reinterpret_cast equivalent in c is just simple casting no?

Comment: in my kernel module I would like to pass the memory address as a module parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert string from argv[1] to unsigned long and assign it to a generic pointer using cast operator (void*), as is shown in example bellow.Be careful, it is dangerous!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   void* ptr = (void*) strtoul(argv[1]+2,0,16);

   printf("%lX", (unsigned long) ptr);

}.
/*
Output:
/a.out 0x123456789abcdef
Result ptr:123456789ABCDEF
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I misunderstood your question, but can you take the pointer and use `printf("%p", ptr);`. Or, if you mean making your program write to the stdin of another program, you can use linux piping for example.

You can also just get the value of the char* address from argv with `reinterpret_cast<WhateverType>(source);`